# Why Javascript array doesn't implode in php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, implode

I actually have this array `var checked_rls= ['24','56'];`

```
            var checked_rls = []
            $("input[name='chk_cont[]']:checked").each(function ()
            {
                checked_rls.push($(this).val());
            });
```

and then I tried to pass it using AJAX

```
  $.ajax(
            {
                type :"POST",
                url : "sale_ajax.php",
                data: 
                {
                    rls :  checked_rls,
                    rls_date : $("#rls_date").val()
                },
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    alert('saved successfully');

                },
                error: function()
                {
                    alert("Failure");
                }
            });
```

and then i received the array in sale_ajax.php file like this `$cont = $_POST['rls'];`

Now the problem is that I can run this array in a forEach function, but when I tried to implode this array into a string it only returns one value.

For e.g. in this scenario I passed 24,56 and when I tried to `implode(",",$cont)`; it only returns the very first value, 24:

```
var_dump($cont) output is
array(2){[0]=>string(2) "24" [1]=>string(2) "56"}
```

and the php code is:

```
if(isset($_POST['rls']))
    {
        $rls_date = $_POST['rls_date'];
        $cont = $_POST['rls'];
        $rls_cont_sold = implode(",",$cont);

         $rls_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO release_details (release_date, cont_sold_id) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('$rls_date', '%d-%m-%Y'), '$rls_cont_sold')")or die(mysql_error());          
         $id = mysql_insert_id();

        foreach($cont as $val)
        {       
          $cont_sold_update = "UPDATE cont_sold SET release_details_id = '$id' WHERE cont_sold_id = '$val'";
          $insert = mysql_query($cont_sold_update)or die(mysql_error());         
        }
    }
```

and the var_dump($_POST) is

```
array(2){ 
["rls"]=>(array(2){[0]=>string(2) "24" [1]=>string(2) "56"})
["rls_date"]=>string(10) "10-04-2015"
}
```

What is actually happening in this condition?
Thank you

Comment: Can you paste `var_dump($cont);`'s output?

Comment: Where is `checked_rls`?

Comment: array(2){[0]=>string(2) "24"  [1]=>string(2) "56"}

Comment: To add details to your question, use the "edit" link under the question, not comments.

Comment: Add you `php` code also.

Comment: @b0s3 updated php code of sale_ajax.php page

Comment: Code looks fine. Can you add `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: You mean, you get 24 inserted into your database?

Comment: @frz3993 yes.. i want to stroe 24,56 but why implode doesnt work dont know reason

Comment: @b0s3 Updated var_dump($_POST)

Comment: Might be the field type or length of the field. Try to check it out

Comment: Try `var_dump($rls_cont_sold)` to see if it implodes correctly, if it shows correctly then i think the problem is with your `INSERT` query

Comment: try to `alert` your array values , to check was there any problem in array before passing to ajax

Comment: @Munna your code is working fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below code in `click` event of `chk_count` element:-

```
$("input[name='chk_cont[]']").click(function(){         
          var checked_rls = [];
            $("input[name='chk_cont[]']:checked").each(function ()
            {
                checked_rls.push($(this).val());
            });
});
```

Comment: same result. only can able save first digit. implode not working

Comment: Try to var_dump($_POST['rls']);

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing passing an array why don't you pass a string itself, it will reduce your number of steps.

```
       var checked_rls = "";
        $("input[name='chk_cont[]']:checked").each(function ()
        {
            checked_rls += $(this).val()+",";
        });
```

Comment: you should add some separator between two values